# Lengths of lines within individual but overlapping buffers?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geoprocessing, arcgis-10.2, statistics

I have a set of points for which I have created a 12 mile buffer.

Eventually, I would like to know how many kilometers of road exist within each buffer zone individually?

The problem I see going forward is that the buffers have overlap.

I need each buffer to be individually selectable so that I can apply my roads layer and obtain the desired information.

Comment: Can you clarify. Input Dissolve type none should achieve this. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000800000019000000. Now if you want to get rid of the overlap you need to decide which buffer if any you want to "own" the overlap.

Comment: as suggested above, use dissolve type 'none' to achieve individual buffer zones.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I did create my buffers in that fashion. I guess my question is where to go from here regarding my roads layer? I want to be able to apply my roads layer so that I can select each individual polygon and it will tell me the number of kilos in each polygon.

Comment: To further clarify, as it sits right now, if I select my road layer it gives me the total kilos for all polygons. I'm looking to select each individual polygon and know the kilos of that polygon.

Comment: Have you ever worked with an iterator in model builder?

Comment: mapBaker, I have not. My GIS experience is somewhat limited. I'm a wildlife biologist. Our GIS person retired recently and we haven't hired a new one yet. Using what little training I have to get some data ready for a statistical model.

Comment: @EricSmith I guess before going into detail, how many points are we talking here?

Comment: 57 points total.

Comment: @EricSmith There's a way to do this using ArcGIS model builder, iterators, and a few other tools, but its dirty, and doesn't lend itself well to any automated reporting based on the results. I've been trying to put together a model that will do it, but I can only go so far as to creating clipped and dissolved sections of the road network based on each of the buffered points. But the issue is there is no way to link back the road segments back to the points!!!

Comment: @mapBaker, that's what I've been dealing with. I created buffers, dissolved and clipped. There is no way of separating the roads to each individual point/buffer area. Essentially, I want the function of 'merge' to happen but they are different feature classes (lines and polygons)

Comment: @EricSmith this is something more easily handled in a spatial relational database such as PostGIS or MS SQL Server... I'm going to try doing this in MSSQL for fun... I'll let you know what I find... sorry I couldn't do more! Frustrating!

Comment: @mapBaker, I appreciate your help. This is very frustrating indeed. I hope you can figure it out so, at the very least, you learn a new trick.

Comment: @EricSmith posted a SQL spatial solution...

Comment: @EricSmith I guess on 2nd thought (maybe 8th or 9th) you could spatially join the clipped and dissolved lines back to the original point buffers and hope to get an ID from there for further summary analysis...

Comment: @EricSmith any luck on this?

Comment: @mapBaker, Chris W's solution worked. I was able get the roads layer selectable within each individual buffer zone.

Comment: @EricSmith be sure to mark his solution as the answer to your question... glad it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to do this directly in ArcGIS and it's fairly simple. It's the same answer I posted to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/98518/calculate-line-distances-inside-of-polygon/), with a slight change in process output since you have overlapping buffers.

1. Give your buffers a unique name attribute (rather than just using
   oid, which you could do, but having a (short) name to follow will
   make it easier).
2. Now you need your roads split at all your buffer boundaries, or at
   least some way to determine which segments (and portions) are in
   which buffer. You can't use Union (which would be a good solution
   given its output) because it only takes polygons. A Spatial Join
   also won't work in this case because while it could assign road
   segments to multiple buffers, it won't cut the roads at the
   boundaries. But you do have two other choices.

   You can use [Intersect](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Intersect/00080000000p000000/) or [Identity](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Identity/00080000000n000000/) (requires an Advanced
   license) on your roads and buffer layer. The result should be a road
   layer that is cut up into segments wherever a road crosses a buffer
   line. A new attribute will be added to the road segments with your
   buffer names. If a road lies in more than one buffer it will be
   duplicated so that there are two records for the segment, one with
   each name. Intersect will give you only the segments in buffers
   (maybe preferable?), whereas Identity will give you all the roads -
   those not in buffers will have no name attribute value.
3. Now you get the total length of all roads in any given buffer. There
   are a couple of ways to do this, including using selections.

   The simplest would be to open the attribute table of your new road
   layer, right-click on the name field, and choose Summarize. Make
   sure the name field is selected as your Summarize field, then in the
   lower box find the Shape_Length field, click the plus next to it and
   check the box for sum. The resulting output should be a table with
   the total length of all road segments by buffer name (make sure you
   have no records selected or clear that check box). The units will be
   in CRS units, so you may need to convert to miles or feet or
   kilometers or whatever your desired output unit is.

   You can also use the [Summary Statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000001z000000) tool. You'll put the
   length field in as your statistic field with a type of sum, and then
   you'll add name field as a case fields. This tool would let you
   incorporate it into a model if needed (Summarize is only available
   through the GUI).

Comment: Nice - I forgot Intersect will work. Be very careful that you output your file to a *GEODATABASE* - if you output to SHP, the SHAPE_Length field will NOT be updated! It will if you write to GDB, though...

Answer (score 0):

Alright this is a great use of SQL Spatial. This answer is using MS SQL Spatial, but could just as easily be done with PostGIS and I suppose Oracle Spatial (never used it...)

*For this example, I used school points from DPS (sorry can't find them online right now...) and the [street centerlines from City and County of Denver](http://data.denvergov.org/dataset/city-and-county-of-denver-street-centerline) loaded into a SQL Server database ... again PostGIS provides the free version of this solution, but the concept is SQL spatial is well handled to deal with this type of query.*

Here's the query that I used:

```
select 
buffInt.SCHOOL_NAM_SHORT as NameOfInputBuffer
, Round((GEOMETRY::UnionAggregate(shape).STLength())/5280, 2) as LengthInBuffer_Miles
, GEOMETRY::UnionAggregate(shape) as LineGeometryInBuffer

from (
select 
pointBuff.shape.STIntersection(b.shape) as shape 
 , pointBuff.SCHOOL_NAM_SHORT
from 
(
select 
a.shape.STBuffer(3000) as shape
, a.SCHOOL_NAM_SHORT
from GISWork.dpsdata.AllSchools_201314 as a 
) as pointBuff
, GISWork.dpsdata.CCD_Street_Centerlines as b
where pointBuff.shape.STIntersects(b.shape) =1
) as buffInt
group by buffInt.SCHOOL_NAM_SHORT
```

This is basically a few sub-selections:

1: create the buffers around the input points (pointBuff)
2: take the INTERSECTION and INTERSECT (essentially a Clip operation) of the streets and the buffered points (buffInt)
3: aggregate (union) the geometry of each set of clipped streets, grouping by their school name (output field: LineGeometryInBuffer)
4: then also convert that unioned geometry to length using STLength() (field: LineGeometryInBuffer)
5: Get the name of the input point that was carried through all the sub selections so I can then perform some summary on the output values

Here's what the table looks like:

[image]

Here's a picture of the lines within each buffer unioned together:

[image]

...and though its hard to see, the buffers DO overlap, and the lines within each buffer do actually overlap which proves that we are in fact getting the lines within each buffer even if the buffers overlap:

[image]

I love SQL Spatial!!!