# How to extract data from a polyline layer in a specified area(Arcgis)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile

I am trying to extract data from a polyline layer within set radii of preselected sites.  I have extracted other data from rasters using the Sample tool and rasters of the area of interest.  I would like to do something similar for polyline data.

[image: Image showing clipped lines in green, original layer source in blue and 1km radius the layer was clipped by in black]

Image showing clipped lines in green, original layer source in blue and 1km radius the layer was clipped by in black

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102573/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the [Select Layer by Location](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000072000000) tool to select polyline feature at set distacne away from your site layer.

> Selects features in a layer based on a spatial relationship to
> features in another layer. Each feature in the Input Feature Layer is
> evaluated against the features in the Selecting Features layer or
> feature class; if the specified Relationship is met, the input feature
> is selected.

Once selected, right click layer in table of contents and select Data>Export Data to extract to new layer.

Comment: I have tried the majority of the 'relationships' and they all seem to leave lines unselected at the edge of the sample circle.  Any lines crossing the boundary are either not selected or their entire length is selected rather then bisected.  Perhaps I'm better off clipping all the data?  Although I think I have done this before but the attribute table gave the lengths of the whole line rather then just that which is held within the clip.

Comment: If you clip the data you will have to re-calculate the geometry of the length field.

Comment: I have just clipped a layer but it has also excluded any lines that are bisecting the boundary, is there anyway to change this?

Comment: Can you add an image to your question showing this and provide these details too?

Comment: I have added an example of the clip. Image showing clipped lines in green, original layer source in blue and 1km radius the layer was clipped by in black.  I am unsure why the clip excludes some of the lines (shown in blue) and how to remedy this.  A similar thing was happening using the select by location tool.

Comment: @user13641 Select by Location will not alter geometry. If a feature extends beyond the area of the chosen spatial relationship, the entire feature is still selected. Intersect should have gotten everything. Some interesting things can happen with using a radius depending on what coordinate system you are in (projected vs geographic). If you want only the portions within you must alter the data using Clip or Intersect (and as pointed out recalc length). What clip did you use? I can see no reason there would be any blue lines not covered by green within your circle using the Clip GP.

Comment: I used the clip in the geoprocessing tools.  I cannot figure why it wouldn't clip all lines in the radius.  Is this a bug?

Comment: Tried it again on a different computer, for some unknown reason it worked, a mystery but at least it's working!