# Include polygons that don't contain line segments in Summarize

Tags: arcgis-desktop, vector, summarizing

I would like to get a summary of road lengths per township, but also include townships that have no roads.

Using the first answer from this question [Calculate line distances inside of polygons using ArcGIS for Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/98518/calculate-line-distances-inside-of-polygons-using-arcgis-for-desktop)

...how would I include the polygons (in my case, townships) that don't have any polylines (roads)? The Summarize spreadsheet that outputs only includes that do.

Comment: Join summary to original

Comment: @FelixIP I joined the summary to another layer with the townships. But same idea, thanks!